# git log format: How to remove leading space from %d (ref names) placeholder?

Tags: bash, git, git-log

Currently, I have this setting:

```sh
format='%C(bold blue)%s'           # Commit subject
format+='%C(auto)%d%n'             # (HEAD -> master, origin/master)\n
format+='%C(yellow)%h%C(reset) '   # 4ae4a86
format+='%an, '                    # John Doe,
format+='%C(magenta)%ar%C(reset) ' # 3 days ago
format+='at %C(cyan)%ad%n'         # at 14:17\n   (--date=format:%H:%M)
format+='%b'                       # Commit body
alias gl="git log --graph --all --pretty='$format' --date=format:%H:%M"
unset format
```

Which gives this:

[image: current git log format]

Like `git log --graph --oneline --all`:

[image: git log --graph --oneline --all]

I want to swap the `%d` (ref names) with `%s` (subject):

```sh
format='%C(auto)%d '               # (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
format+='%C(bold blue)%s%n'        # Commit subject\n
```

But it gives a leading space:

[image: first attempt]

As an alternative to `%d`, there's [`%D`, which removes the leading space **and** the parantheses](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emDem). So I replaced `%d` with `%D` and wrap it in parentheses:

```sh
format='%C(auto)(%D) '             # (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
```

But now it looks like this:

[image: latest attempt]

So, how to remove the leading space from `%d` while still retaining the parentheses?